# Nginx: Rewrite/Proxy_Pass without changing original URL

Tags: nginx, redirect

I have searched through several questions on this but not come across my scenario.

Here is what I need:

My customer acmecorporation uses the following URL buysomething.acmecorporation.com/computers when someone online wants to buy computers from site. However, this needs to be redirected to the actual vendor who is selling it - something like:

computers.world.com - every context that acme needs to be translated into
(as an example) printers.world.com

I have managed to that working with the vendor

```
     location /computers {
        rewrite ^/(computers.*)$  https://computers.world.com;
        proxy_set_header request_uri $request_uri;
        proxy_pass https://buysomething.acmecorporation.com/computers;
    }
```

The site opens up correctly - however the URL on the browser changes to computers.world.com. What should the vendor be doing to have the acmecorporation persisted?

Or is it a change on my customer (acmecorporation) side?

Thanks much !

Comment: I believe you won't be able to redirect to an external website maintaining the former url via nginx. However you will be able to do something like it using an iframe in the html.

Comment: I'm looking to do something similar as well.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to redirect to an external website maintaining the former url via nginx. However you will be able to do something like it through [HTML frameset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_frameset.asp).

When `buysomething.acmecorporation.com/computers` is accessed your application should render the html below (no `<html>` or `<body>` tags):

```
<frameset rows="100%">
  <frameset cols="100%">
    <frame src="https://computers.world.com" frameborder="0" >
  </frameset>
</frameset>
```

That way `computers.world.com` will be loaded inside your page and the URL will not change.

Comment: Yes this I was able to. But was looking from nginx standpoint. Thanks!

Comment: You can't unless the destination web server you are pointing at is configured to respond for the hostname buysomething.acmecorporation.com. What I don't believe it's possible in your scenario, since the redirection point is a third party site.